# cypress - how to compare href to anchor text

Tags: cypress

I'm wondering how to test using cypress libary if the href attribute include the text from anchor tag. The code is as follow:

I have a div with a lot of anchors with data attribute.

```
<div>
    <a href="/tag/hash1/" data-cy="hashtags">#hash1</a>
    <a href="/tag/hash2/" data-cy="hashtags">#hash2</a>
    <a href="/tag/hash3/" data-cy="hashtags">#hash3</a>
    // and many more
</div>
```

I stared testing with check if each element have "#", href attribute with "/tag/" :

```
describe('Test', () => {
  
  it('should navigate to link from hashtag', () => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.get('[data-cy="hashtag"]').each((item) => {
      cy.wrap(item).contains('#').should('have.attr', 'href').and('contain', '/tag/');
    })
  })
});
```

but **how can I check if href include the displayed text from a tag?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've yielded the element from your `cy.get()`, you can reference it as a jQuery object. [In this case, we'll want to get the text.](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
describe('Test', () => {
  
  it('should navigate to link from hashtag', () => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.get('[data-cy="hashtag"]').each((item) => {
      cy.wrap(item).contains('#').should('have.attr', 'href', `/tag/${item.text().replace('#', '')}`)
    })
  })
});
```

If you simply wanted to see if the href contains the text, you could use the [jQuery `attr` function.](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
describe('Test', () => {
  
  it('should navigate to link from hashtag', () => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.get('[data-cy="hashtag"]').each((item) => {
      expect(item.text()).to.contain('#');
      expect(item.attr('href')).to.contain(item.text().replace('#', ''));
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: It work's fine, thank you! :)